How to use MS Access button in Main form to update list box in Subform?
I am building a Microsoft Access database form that has a couple of subforms, each in their own tab in a tab control. I also have a list box inside one of the subforms that displays all records that match the Primary Key of the record open in the main form. Let's call those primary records A, B, C... and the subform records that match 1,2,3...
Maybe in the subform table that looks like this
Record MainRecordKey  
1      A  
2      A  
3      A  
4      B  
5      B  
6      B  

I want to create a button in the main form that both switches to the next Primary Key record in the main form and updates that list box to show the correct information.
I have made a button that updates the list with the expression builder . So when I move to record B, I press the button and it updates so that 4,5,6 shows instead of 1,2,3.
That works, but the issue is I cannot find a way to also switch records just using the expression builder. At the same time, I cannot get the list box to update using VBA (I assume I am referencing it wrong). Right now I have, inside the On_Click property VBA editor:
Private Sub GoNext_Click()
     Me![individualsSubformTab].Form!SubformList.Requery
End Sub

From the sources I checked this should be sufficient but I have tried every type of reference I can. "individualSubFormTab" is the name of the Subform control in the main form. "SubformList" is the name of the list box.
No idea about the next steps but I really want to make it work with VBA so I can include the code to go to the next record. I would be happy to provide more info if needed.

The technique you are trying to apply is know as "cascading" or "dependent" combo/list box. Is the name individualsSubformTab or individualSubformTab? The first is in code and the second in your narrative.

The VBA you show should work (although I would use dot in place of ! mark). Actually, a combo/list box with the dependency you describe doesn't make sense to me. Could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

Here is the painful to use guide to relative references in access: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm  Each form and control does have an absolute name but I've never found a reference for how to find it consistently.

If a subform isn't working it is probably a problem with the subform's master and child fields.  For instance when you have a 1 to many relationship between  a teachers table and a students table where TeacherID is the teachers table primary key and TeacherID is the students table foreign key.  If you also have the relationship between the tables added in the relationship tool, then if you select the teachers table and auto create a form Access correctly makes a teachers form with a students subform.  Study that.  The most common error is to remove TeacherID from the subform record source
